# pandas: naming index of results from groupby on multiple parsed dates

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a data frame with a `datetime64` column called `eventTime`. If I do:

```
df.groupby([df.eventTime.dt.year, df.eventTime.dt.month, df.eventTime.dt.day])['id'].count()
```

I get a dataframe with multiple index but all name the same with `eventTime`. Something like:

```
eventTime  eventTime   eventTime
     2017          2          23          1
                   3          20          4
Name: id, dtype: int64
```

How do I set proper names for the resulting dataframe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of any way to do this as part of the groupby function, but you can easily rename the index of the grouped DataFrame afterwards:

```
df.index.rename(['Y', 'M', 'D'], inplace=True)
```

Note: `df` here is the grouped DataFrame. In your real example you'll likely want to assign the result of your `df.groupby()` call to some other variable unless you won't need the raw data again.